# Drools Planner constructionHeuristic java.lang.ClassCastException

Tags: java, drools, drools-planner

I tried to initialize the solution using **Drools Planner 5.4.Final** Contruction Heuristic Type BEST_FIT.

```
<constructionHeuristic>
    <constructionHeuristicType>BEST_FIT</constructionHeuristicType>
</constructionHeuristic>
```

The following error occurs during evaluation at runtime

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.drools.planner.config.constructionheuristic.ConstructionHeuristicSolverPhaseConfig cannot be cast to org.drools.planner.config.localsearch.LocalSearchSolverPhaseConfig
```

Does anybody have any hints?

Thanks

This is the stacktrace

```
com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException: Element constructionHeuristic of type org.drools.planner.config.constructionheuristic.ConstructionHeuristicSolverPhaseConfig is not defined as field in type org.drools.planner.config.localsearch.LocalSearchSolverPhaseConfig
---- Debugging information ----
class               : org.drools.planner.config.localsearch.LocalSearchSolverPhaseConfig
required-type       : org.drools.planner.config.localsearch.LocalSearchSolverPhaseConfig
converter-type      : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.ReflectionConverter
line number         : 23
class[1]            : org.drools.planner.config.solver.SolverConfig
version             : null
-------------------------------
com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter: writeValueToImplicitCollection (line:399)
com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter: doUnmarshal (line:330)
com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter: unmarshal (line:230)
com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller: convert (line:72)
com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller: convert (line:65)
com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller: convertAnother (line:66)
com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller: convertAnother (line:50)
com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter: doUnmarshal (line:318)
com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter: unmarshal (line:230)
com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller: convert (line:72)
com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller: convert (line:65)
com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller: convertAnother (line:66)
com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller: convertAnother (line:50)
com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller: start (line:134)
com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy: unmarshal (line:32)
com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream: unmarshal (line:1035)
com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream: unmarshal (line:1019)
com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream: fromXML (line:895)
org.drools.planner.config.XmlSolverFactory: configure (line:95)
org.drools.planner.config.XmlSolverFactory: configure (line:85)
org.drools.planner.config.XmlSolverFactory: configure (line:78)
```

Comment: What's the full stacktrace? BTW: it's really worth upgrading to 5.5 (for JIT stuff) and then to 6.0 (for speedups etc). Just follow the upgrade recipe txt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the stacktrace you're doing something like

```
<solver>
  ...
  <localSearch>
    <constructionHeuristic>
       ...    
    </constructionHeuristic>
    ...
  </localSearch>
<solver>
```

while it should be something like:

```
<solver>
  ...
  <constructionHeuristic>
    ...    
  </constructionHeuristic>
  <localSearch>
    ...
  </localSearch>
<solver>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your suggestion. I attached the wrong stacktrace because the several attemps I made.
The problem was (in my code) these line:
LocalSearchSolverPhaseConfig localSearchSolverPhaseConfig = (LocalSearchSolverPhaseConfig) configurer.getSolverConfig().getSolverPhaseConfigList().get(0);
localSearchSolverPhaseConfig.getForagerConfig().setMinimalAcceptedSelection(options.getDepthSearch());

Comment: Because before, in the config.xml, I had only one solver phase.
I corrected my code but, unfortunately, in my problem I have 2 planning entity and the heuristic only support one:
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Currently the greedyFit implementation only supports 1 planningEntityImplementationClass.

Comment: @TommasoTaruffi Upgrade to OptaPlanner (= Drools Planner) `6.0.0.CR4` or later, that supports CH's with multiple planning entities.

Comment: Follow the [upgrade recipe](https://github.com/droolsjbpm/optaplanner/blob/master/optaplanner-distribution/src/main/assembly/filtered-resources/UpgradeFromPreviousVersionRecipe.txt)